# C# duplicate DataTable but only insert rows where one value is unique

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code:

`DataTable uniqueCou = CouponResult.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "URL");`

This is fine exact it only adds the value URL, what I want is all 4 columns from CouponResult which are (URL,Key,Item,Value).  When I use the above code it just returns a one column unique Datatable.

What I really want is to insert all the rows where "URL" is unique with all the other columns.  If i include the other 3 columns in DefaultView.ToTable(true, "URL");` the result is actually not unique.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `CouponResult` doesnot have unique data. Try this,

```
DataTable uniqueCou = CouponResult.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new String[] {"URL","Key","Item","Value"});
```